# informatica mapping to assign values of column1 position1 to column2 position2

Tags: informatica-powercenter

*Input*

```
column1         
11                  
12                
13                     
14
```

*Desired output*

```
Colmn1   column2
11        Null
12        11
13        12
```

I have added the ports in the order as below in expression,

```
column1 - colmn1
V-count - V_count+1
column2 - iif(V_count=1,null,v_col)
V_col   - column1
```

Since I studied as like the order of ports matters the execution order.so I added the v_col at last.
But for  column2 1st position is  null and the remaining values in column2 are as same as column1.

Can anyone tell what should I have to do to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution order does depend on the display order but only for variable ports - the Integration Service first evaluates **input** ports, then the **variable** ones (in the display order) and last the **output** ports ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099614/95)).

You need two variable ports:

```
PORT             EXPRESSION
column1          N/A (for in-out port)
v_prev_column1   v_curr_column1
v_curr_column1   column1
column2          v_prev_column1
```